# Will it affect my CV badly if I quit too early?

Tags: quitting

I have a really tough time to make decision on quitting my current job.
I've been working in this Software Development Company for 4 months now.
However, it is not like I expected, it's a France company in South East Asia.

I have 5 years working experience in 3 different companies and this is the fourth. But never before that I feel this miserable working in this new company.

I am a friendly person, and my formal co-workers like me a lot. I like to get along with co-workers and I like to share ideas. However, in this company, I feel everyone is so passive, perhaps because the colleagues are much older than me (their age from 35 above). No-one talks to each other during work or even lunch time. It's so quiet with only the sound of typing.

But it's still OK for me, the main problem is my CTO/CEO. I never met and worked with such a dictator as this.

I've never seen a boss scold the employees this badly, he scolds everyone, yells at everyone that does not do as he expected.  He is extremely short tempered. My team leader got scolded until she shed tears in front of everyone.

You might say he's the boss and he has the right. I'd accept that, but moreover he keeps coming to stare at my screen every 30 minutes - literally - during project starts. I feel really uncomfortable.  Worst, he keeps saying that "the company is paying you guys money, so make sure don't waste our company money..." even though we work hard. Never before have I felt so useless.

Now, he even banned Skype. Meaning, we can only communicate via email, and face-to-face.

I can deal with stress from project deadlines or overtime, but working in a place like this making me nervous.  I don't know what's going to happen to me if I might do something wrong every minute. I got very exhausted with the atmosphere, and have no reason to contribute, I feel like a dead person every day walking into this office, I want to quit, but my friends and family advised me to bear it at least a year, or else it doesn't look good on my CV.

But every day feels like a year working like this.

Please advise me that I should quit or not in this case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nobody can tell you if you should quit. That's a personal decision. *You* have to take that decision, because only *you* will feel the consequences, either good or bad.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes, when manager hire someone they expect you to stay longer than a year, so if they read your CV they probably have some doubt, nevertheless if you have good reason for quitting I think they can understand, but it definitely harder to land a job if you hop around to much. Just make sure you get an offer before you quit this one.

Comment: If Skype is banned, perhaps offer an alternative, [Slack](https://slack.com/). Or ask why it was banned and try get it unbanned for the sake of convenience.

Comment: Find a new job. If someone ask you, tell them that the working enviroment was very bad. Don't spend your life miserable at work.

Comment: @hd, OP has far bigger problems than not being able to use skype :-)

Comment: Thanks guys, I already made up my mind, and sent resignation letter. I don't want to look at someone's temper to work like this. I believe workplace is where you can develop and contribute as the same time. Not the place to be scared. My colleagues say they don't quit because they have family to support and they are quite old to jump around. They say I am still young and single, try some other places more fun. Woo, I am quite shocked hearing that.   Once again thanks guys

Comment: it's not because Skype banning making me unhappy, it's just the way my boss managing company is unusual to me, and his temper is hard to cope. Last week, he banned Internet totally because he saw someone reading online news.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to quit, but my friends and family advise me to bear it at
>   least a year, or else my CV does not look good.

In five years of work, you've held four different jobs. Making that five different jobs won't matter very much. And waiting another 8 months won't change much. It doesn't look good now. It still won't look good in 8 months.

But rather than just quitting, first find a job that you will stick with for longer than a year or so. Try to find a position where you can settle in and enjoy the work for the long run. (It's always best to find your next job while you are still employed. That way, you don't become desperate and settle for less than the "right" job for you).

Think back over your past job hunts. What about them could you have done differently so that you wouldn't have left so soon?

Perhaps you didn't research the company enough. Perhaps you didn't network well, and thus didn't have someone who could give you "inside" information about the company. Certainly, you didn't learn enough about the kind of boss you would be working for.

Consider this a learning opportunity and prepare to do it differently next time.

You don't want to come across as "flighty" or a "job hopper". There isn't much you can do to change that impression right now - other than landing a job that you will be happy with for the long haul.

Answer (score 2):

Life is too short to waste on being in a job where you are miserable. In five years time you will look back and wonder why you put up with it as long as you did. Get out as fast as you can and don't look back- You can always come up with a positive and decent explanation for a short job on your resume, but you cannot get back wasted time being angry and miserable.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody can tell you if you should quit. That's a personal decision. You have to take that decision, because only you will feel the consequences, either good or bad.

Some things you should consider:

- You will need another job. Already having another job when you quit would make sense.
- Your life is not endless. Wasting a year of it being miserable is not worth it.

So in the end, there is no harm in *looking* for another job immediately.